# Looping through a String

Tags: javascript, string, split

I want to get every word that is shown after the word `and`.

```
var s = "you have a good day and time works for you and I'll make sure to 
get the kids together and that's why I was asking you to do the needful and 
confirm"

for (var  i= 0 ; i <= 3; i++){
    var body = s;
    var and = body.split("and ")[1].split(" ")[0];
    body = body.split("and ")[1].split(" ")[1];
    console.log(and);
}
```

How do I do this?!

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by: *I want to get every word that is shown after the word*

Comment: Is this your expectation? ["time", "I'll", "that's", "confirm"]

Comment: every word after to word "and"

Comment: What if your statement contains "sand"?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest thing is probably to use a regular expression looking for "and" followed by whitespace followed by the "word" after it, for instance something like `/\band\s*([^\s]+)/g`:

```js
var s = "you have a good day and time works for you and I'll make sure to get the kids together and that's why I was asking you to do the needful and confirm";
var rex = /\band\s*([^\s]+)/g;
var match;
while ((match = rex.exec(s)) != null) {
  console.log(match[1]);
}
```

You may well need to tweak that a bit (for instance, `\b` ["word boundary"] considers `-` a boundary, which you may not want; and separately, your definition of "word" may be different from `[^\s]+`, etc.).

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks, everyone for the replies. i was scraping a website for image urls sorry for the lack of detail.

Answer (score 0):

at first you need to split the whole string in "and ", after that you have to split every element of given array into spaces, and the first element of the second given array will be the first word after the "and" word.

```
  var s = "you have a good day and time works for you and I'll make sure to get the kids together and that's why I was asking you to do the needful and confirm"


        var body = s;
        var and = body.split("and ");
        for(var i =0; i<and.length;i++){
        console.log(and[i].split(" ")[0]);
        }
```

Comment: Code dumps are not *useful* answers. Say *what* you did, and *why*.

Answer (score 0):

You can split, check for "and" word, and get next one:

```js
var s = "you have a good day and time works for you and I'll make sure to get the kids together and that's why I was asking you to do the needful and confirm";
var a = s.split(' ');
var cont = 0;
var and = false;

while (cont < a.length) {
  if (and) {
    console.log(a[cont]); 
  }
  and = (a[cont] == 'and');
  cont++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this using `replace`

```
var s = "you have a good day and time works for you and I'll make sure to get the kids together and that's why I was asking you to do the needful and confirm"

s.replace(/and\s+([^\s]+)/ig, (match, word) => console.log(word))
```